# Highlight Gridpane Cell on Mouseover JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

Okay so as said above I have gridpane in my javafx application and im trying to get it so that when I mouse over an individual cell the cell that the mouse is over will change color to a yellow (think excell kinda thing). Ive got no idea how to do this and then reset it after the mouse leaves the cell.

```
  officeHoursGridPane.setOnMouseEntered((MouseEvent t) -> {
        officeHoursGridPane.setStyle("-fx-background- color:#FFFF00;");
  });

  officeHoursGridPane.setOnMouseEntered((MouseEvent t) -> {
       officeHoursGridPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#dae7f3;");
  });
```

This is how I have it right now but it just changes the one color at mouse over and then stays that color. The entire table also changes not each cell. Anyone help?

Comment: Why do you have two completely contradictory handlers for the same event on the same node? What are you expecting that to do? I recommend you read some of the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) pages on asking questions, particularly [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."*.

Answer (score 1):

If you set a style class on the grid pane:

```
officeHoursGridPane.getStyleClass().add("office-hours-pane");
```

then you can use CSS to apply styles to the immediate children of the grid pane, and use the built-in `hover` pseudoclass to only apply them when the node is hovered. Add the following to an external CSS file:

```
.office-hours-pane > *:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

If you prefer to use listeners (which is much trickier, and not good practice as you should really separate the style into a separate entity, such as CSS) then you would set `onMouseEntered` and `onMouseExited` listeners on each of the child nodes of the grid pane (not on the grid pane itself).

Comment: I actually ended up finding this answer eventually my self the other day!

Comment: What im having problems with now is getting the column of the cell im highlighing to also change color.